# C Program NEWB: strcpy buffer warning

Tags: c, struct, malloc

(Sorry if duplicate, couldn't find a simple answer to this question)
Learning how to form structures and having buffer warnings when using strcpy.  I'm thinking I need to malloc to create buffer space?  I thought defining the array did that.  I added +1 to the strcpy length to accommodate the string term /0... but still getting warnings.  Your help is greatly appreciated...

CODE:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char id[9] = "123456789";
char fn[20] = "firstname";
char ln[20] = "lastname";
char bd[10] = "99/99/1900";
int h = 72;
int w = 215;

typedef struct PERSON {

    char ID[9];
    char firstName[20];
    char lastName[20];
    char birthDate[10];
    int height;
    int weight;
    int BMI;

}PERSON;

int main() {

    PERSON p1;

    strcpy_s(p1.ID, 10, id);
    strcpy_s(p1.firstName, 21, fn);
    strcpy_s(p1.lastName, 21, ln);
    strcpy_s(p1.birthDate, 11, bd);
    p1.height = h;
    p1.weight = w;
    p1.BMI = (p1.weight / (p1.height * p1.height) * 703);

    printf("ID: %s\nFirst Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nBirth Date: %s\nHeight: %d\nWeight: %d\nBMI: %d\n", p1.ID, p1.firstName, p1.lastName, p1.birthDate, p1.height, p1.weight, p1.BMI);

    return 0;


}
```

Output:  I'm getting firstname showing up on the ID line, telling me I'm having some memory issues?

```
ID: 123456789firstname
First Name: firstname
Last Name: lastname
Birth Date: 99/99/1900
Height: 72
Weight: 215
BMI: 0

C:\Users\.................ep.exe (process 56868) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

If I change this:
`strcpy_s(p1.ID, 10, id);`
to:
`strcpy_s(p1.ID, 9, id);`
the code doesn't complile. I get a Debug Assertion Failed.  Buffer is too small. reinforcing my thoughts on memory issues.

Not too familiar with malloc.  will I need to malloc all arrays within the struct?
Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Heard of the 0 terminator? `char id[9] = "123456789";` is an array of 9 chars, but you are trying to put 10 into it. 1-9 plus the 0 terminator (that comes after 9)

Comment: @John3136 I have, it was just a counting error... clerical errors are the worst... thanks

Comment: That's why magic numbers are bad :) `char id[] = "123456789";` works and then you can do `sizeof(id)` (which includes the 0 terminator) later on.

Comment: @John3136 great idea! thanks for the tip... I think I did read that in my text... this was suppose to be a study on structs which I was happy with, I found the lesson to be with memory and proofreading... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `9` characters

`"123456789";`

you need array of length `10` to accommodate `\0` char.

```
char ID[10];
....

typedef struct PERSON {

char ID[10];
```

Comment: I thought it would be something simple like that... lol... still learning to count evidently... thanks! that took away the warnings...